# facebook channel -- bot framework issue

Tags: facebook-graph-api, botframework, facebook-messenger-bot

So I made a bot using Bot Framework v4 Nodejs SDK and while the bot was healthy and running just yesterday. Today, something peculiar happened in the bot, only through facebook channel.

So whenever someone sends a message in the bot through messenger: the from object contains {"id":"3012023272144004","name":"FACEBOOK_USER_NAME"}

this is displayed in my code:
 `console.log("FROM DATA : " + JSON.stringify(stepContext.context.activity.from));`

today it only displays {"id":"3012023272144004","name":" "} where the facebook name of user is always empty (and I assure you that users,that I tested, has a facebook name)

also whenever I request for facebook firstname and lastname using graph API I have this response 
`{"error":{"message":"(#80006) There have been too many messenger api calls to this Page account. Wait a bit and try again. For more info, please refer to https:\/\/developers.facebook.com\/docs\/graph-api\/overview\/rate-limiting.","type":"OAuthException","code":80006,"fbtrace_id":"AZp9laYMB2IGha-WAPYDBXH"}}`

I retried it for the whole day, and nothing happened. I checked the dashboard for rate limit but all I can see is 0% limit used (the app is exclusively connected to my page and the page is exclusively connected to my app. thanks for the clarification)

and this never happened before, I always get the firstname, lastname, id and even profile picture - sample body response from previous calls: 
`{"first_name":"Nightshade","last_name":"Villabrille","profile_pic":"https:\/\/platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com\/platform\/profilepic\/?psid=2951340481545239&width=1024&ext=1586604925&hash=AeTsZ60vo4npjquO","id":"2951340481545239"}`

I really have no idea where to ask this issue. Is this framework issue? facebook graph issue? or bot channels issue? Thanks!

---I'll provide code or respond to anything that I need to clarify. Thanks!

PS: Even other channels responds like this on email: `{"id":"apvillabrille@up.edu.ph","name":"Villabrille, Aleimar P."}` and webchat: `{"id":"3012023272144004","name":"Web Chat User","role":"user"}`

Comment: _“(and this is expected as I'm the only one chatting the bot at the moment)”_ - the message is not talking about your bot, it is talking about the page. That is the level the limit is applied on, so if there’s other apps interacting with the same page, they share those resources.

Comment: @CBroe I see. But I assure you that my app is connected exclusively on my page.

Comment: @AleimarVillabrille - It will be hard to guess what the problem is since I can't reproduce it. Supposing it was some kind of temporary outage, can you let us know if you're still experiencing the issue? I notice that you posted [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/issues/885#issuecomment-598582444) on a closed GitHub issue originally. Please link to all the sources you're using, such as the specific Facebook Graph API you mentioned. (Since there are multiple people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: hey @KyleDelaney , I don't know exactly what happened. But the channels works just fine now. This is really strange for me as I didn't do anything in the bot. I just leave it in hopes of seeing a better response from the [thread](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/issues/885#issuecomment-598582444) , was there any changes in bot channels during that time? If so, when can we know if there would be some minor changes in bot framework. Thanks!

Comment: Did it failed to you again? I am facing this issue right now but with every bot, it just send the name when the user has a role in the facebook app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Azure Bot Service change log is not currently available to the public, and the problem you experienced may not have had an entry in the change log anyway. It's unclear if the problem was on your end or Facebook's end or Microsoft's end, and if it was on Microsoft's end then it was more likely to have been a random outage than an actual code update. If your production bot experiences problems like this in the future then you can submit a support request through your bot resource in the Azure portal.

[image]

You might also consider engaging with the Facebook developer community: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/useful-resources

Comment: Hi @KyleDelaney . This error happened again and apparently its due to "People have been reporting content that your Page is sending. In the interest of our users, your Page has been blocked from sending messages via the Messenger Platform. This block may be active for 24 hours." I believe this is unfair, because you didn't let us know why exactly are we being banned, and at least notify hours before silencing our bot. Business should have rights to defend against this. FYI, ads are running and our reputation is highly impacted.

Comment: Well that's Facebook for you. Why didn't you see that message last time?

Comment: compared last time, I asked for azure support for this one. they inspected errors in their end and saw that message.